# using toJSON: How to get an array nested in a data.frame into a JSON object

Tags: r, json, dataframe

I am trying to convert a data.frame into JSON text. How can I include an array in this data.frame? I.e. the variable characteristics needs to contain multiple elements. I do not succeed in this.

Here is my code:

```
data <- data.frame(sequenceNbr = c(1:3),
                   requestTypeCode = "MR001",
                   managementStartingDate = format(Sys.Date(),"%Y-%m-%d"),
                   TopicCode = "TH02",
                   Nbr = c("1760448", "6580364", "1391363"),
                   TypeCode = "R003008",
                   char1 = "CK001001", char2 = "CK001002",
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
  group_by(sequenceNbr) %>%
  nest( Assignment=c(TopicCode),
        entity = c(Nbr),
        ToControl = c(TypeCode),
        characteristics = c(char1,char2)
        ) 


data <- data %>%
  mutate(   Assignment = purrr::map(Assignment, as.list),
          entity = purrr::map(entity, as.list)) 


json <- jsonlite::toJSON(list(`DefList`=data),
                         auto_unbox = TRUE, pretty = TRUE)
```

This gives as output

```
{
  "DefList": [
    {
      "sequenceNbr": 1,
      "requestTypeCode": "MR001",
      "managementStartingDate": "2020-06-16",
      "Assignment": {
        "TopicCode": "TH02"
      },
      "entity": {
        "Nbr": "1760448"
      },
      "ToControl": [
        {
          "TypeCode": "R003008"
        }
      ],
      "characteristics": [
        {
          "char1": "CK001001",
          "char2": "CK001002"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "sequenceNbr": 2,
      "requestTypeCode": "MR001",
      "managementStartingDate": "2020-06-16",
      "Assignment": {
        "TopicCode": "TH02"
      },
      "entity": {
        "Nbr": "6580364"
      },
      "ToControl": [
        {
          "TypeCode": "R003008"
        }
      ],
      "characteristics": [
        {
          "char1": "CK001001",
          "char2": "CK001002"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

What I want as output is this (there is a difference in the characteristics-element):

```
{
  "DefList": [
    {
      "sequenceNbr": 1,
      "requestTypeCode": "MR001",
      "managementStartingDate": "2020-06-16",
      "Assignment": {
        "TopicCode": "TH02"
      },
      "entity": {
        "Nbr": "1760448"
      },
      "ToControl": [
        {
          "TypeCode": "R003008"
        }
      ],
      "characteristics": [
          "CK001001",
          "CK001002"
      ]
    },
    {
      "sequenceNbr": 2,
      "requestTypeCode": "MR001",
      "managementStartingDate": "2020-06-16",
      "Assignment": {
        "TopicCode": "TH02"
      },
      "entity": {
        "Nbr": "6580364"
      },
      "ToControl": [
        {
          "TypeCode": "R003008"
        }
      ],
      "characteristics": [
          "CK001001",
          "CK001002"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

It should also work when characteristics contains only one value. Any idea's? I think the data.frame structure is the limiting factor, since it cannot contain an array. I see in this post : https://blog.exploratory.io/working-with-json-data-in-very-simple-way-ad7ebcc0bb89 that it is correct JSON syntax, but I do not manage to obtain it. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You can add `characteristics = purrr::map(characteristics, ~ unname(as.list(.)))` inside your `mutate()`. Does that do what you want?

Comment: Thanks Bas! This is indeed what I needed.